# No space left on device: Amazon Sagemaker can't save more files in directory even when HDD is not full

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker

I'm getting the OS error: No space left on device, when saving somewhere north of 17 million small files into a single directory on Amazon Sagemaker local storage. I'm using the `numpy.save` function, python 3.8.12. `df -h` shows that the drive is only about 80% full. `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max` returns 6,269,329, which is a lot less than the number of saved files, `df -i` returns 28% IUse% for the parent folder. What could be the problem here?

Comment: where did you save the files? is that in a Notebook instance or a Training job?

Comment: The files are saved by a python script which I ran from a Jupyter Lab terminal.

Comment: And is it SageMaker Notebook Instance or SageMaker Studio Notebook?

Comment: It's a Notebook Instance

Answer (score 0):

SageMaker Notebook instance are equipped with an "ML Volume" mounted at `/home/ec2-user/SageMaker`, whose size you can control, and that is 5GB by default, and that can be up to 16TB.

If you have the right permissions, you can increase volume size (it requires to switch off the instance and restart it)
Then, edit your code to make sure it writes to that folder

Comment: I have a 1TB mounted volume. Even though ```df``` shows only about ±80% usage, I get the "No space left" message.

Comment: ok so that's probably because you don't write to the right disk? do you write specifically to /home/ec2-user/SageMaker? you may have a process writing files to /home/ec2-user or other